# Value of a Row in Binding

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I created a `GridLenght` property, whose value I put it in `Binding` in a `Row` within a `Grid`. In my case the value should be around 40 units, but the `collectionview` inserted in that `Row` takes the full length of the screen.

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="{Binding HeightEmoji}"/>
//other code
```

c#:

```
 public GridLength HeightEmoji { get; set; }

 public MainPage()
 {
      HeightEmoji = (MyList.Count / 5) * 40;
 }
```

Comment: what is the BindingContext of your Grid/Page?

Comment: I haven't assigned it. how should I assign it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine what the other answers and comments have said, you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged with correct binding.

In your code behind, implement INotifyPropertChanged:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

HeightEmoji needs a backing field and needs to to call OnPropertyChanged:

```
private GridLength heightEmoji;
public GridLength HeightEmoji
{
    get => heightEmoji;
    set
    {
        heightEmoji = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(HeightEmoji));
    }
}
```

In the constructor, you need to set the binding context:

```
public MainPage()
{
    BindingContext = this; 
    InitializeComponent();
    HeightEmoji = (MyList.Count / 5) * 40;
}
```

Then in your XAML you do your binding:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="{Binding HeightEmoji}"/>
//other code
```

I would note that with the way you have initial call to set HeightEmoji in the ctor, if `MyList.Count` changes after setting, your row height will not change.

The better work around would be to bind the row height to a converter.

Comment: it works! thanks, but you are right that that value does not update. How could I solve? What does the converter consist of?

Answer (score 0):

1. In MainPage class, you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged
2. In the set property of HeightEmoji, you need to call OnPropertyChanged()
3. In the data binding, you need UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged

   Height="{Binding HeightEmoji, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"